# How can I set image view which stored in file system according to path in database?

Tags: android, image, filesystems, filepath

I have three questions:

1. If I choose to store `image.png` in file system where should I store it `res/drawable/image_1.png`  or `res/drawable/images/image_1.png`
2. And I'm going to store path of image in database. What should I put in `image_path` field ex. `image_1` or `images/image_1` or etc.
3. How can I get path of image from database and set image to view follow my code in the bottom? Could you guys change it for me?

### I already have answer

1. in case storing image file in file system in `assets/images/pic_1.png`
2. In database, "image_path field" , you will put `images/pic_1.png` in it.
3. To get and set image: according to Trim's answer.

AND I have fixed the following code according to Trim's answer.

Thanks so much

**placeListActivity.class**

```
public class placeListActivity extends ListActivity {
   
    private static MyDB mDbHelper;
    String[] from = new String[] { Constants.COL_TITLE};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.list_place_title};
    private Cursor c;

    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        
        mDbHelper = new MyDB(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        mDbHelper.open();
        c = mDbHelper.getAllPlaces();

        
        setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                  R.layout.list_place, c, 
                  from, to));
        
        final ListView lv = getListView();
          
        
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), Place.class);    
                i.putExtra(Constants.KEY_ID, id);
                i.putExtra(Constants.COL_TITLE, c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Constants.COL_TITLE)));
                i.putExtra(Constants.COL_CONTENT, c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Constants.COL_CONTENT)));
 
                i.putExtra(Constants.COL_IMAGE, c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Constants.COL_IMAGE)));
                
                
                
                startActivity(i);
            
            }
          });
        
        
    }

}
```

**Place.class**

```
public class Place extends Activity {
    
    private TextView title;
    private TextView content;
    private ImageView placeImage;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.detail_place);
        
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_title);
        content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_content);

        placeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.place_image);
        
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
        // reference XML defined views that we will touch in code
        String stringTitle = extras.getString(Constants.COL_TITLE);
        String stringContent = extras.getString(Constants.COL_CONTENT);

        String imageID = extras.getString(Constants.COL_IMAGE);
        
 
        if (title != null) {
            title.setText(stringTitle); 
        }
        if (content != null) {
            content.setText(stringContent);
        }

        /*if (placeImage != null) {
            placeImage.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imageID));
        }*/
        
        if (placeImage != null) {
        
        try {
            InputStream path = getAssets().open(imagePath);
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(path);
            placeImage.setImageBitmap(bit);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can save your images under assets and paths in your db. You can easily access a file in asset folder if you know the path.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: its very clear I think. put your images in asset folder. save the paths in db. getAssets() method will return the path to the assets folder. you will just add the imae path from db to access your image.

Comment: you're right it's very clear but i'm very new to coding i have no idea about that. 1)what's the paths should look like? /assets/images/pic_1.png    << right or wrong>>  2) where can i put getAssets() method in my code above   3) how to setImage: is this ok? placeImage.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imageID));

Comment: I have posted an answer. If you need more help, please read the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) and the [api reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Comment: i will, sometime i have stupid question sorry for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your images under **"assets/images"** directory. In this case, the path that you will use in `getAssets().open(String path)` will be like **"images/pic_1.png".**
You can call `getAssets()` anywhere in your activity.
There is also a `setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)` method.
You can create bitmap from path via `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String path)`.

Comment: anyway, can i put image into others directory? i.e. "res" or etc. Do you have any idea?

Comment: if you put them in res/drawable directory, a resource id is generated for each of them. You can then access them via ids such as "R.id.resource_id_of_your_image".